# Finding odd integer's middle number

Tags: c, arrays

OK, so to be clear I'm counting the distance. If the number is even it's easy to calculate, however if it's odd hmm I have an idea but I can't apply it. The task sounds like so: I need to find the distance between objects. As for example given data:

```
4 // how many objects (n)
4 10 0 12 every object's distance
After sorting the numbers ( im using arrays ) the answer is: (4-0)+(12-10)=6;
```

So my code after sorting even numbers appears to be correct, however when the number is odd calculations are like so:

```
5 (n)
4 10 0 12 2
Answer= (2-0)+(4-2)+(12-10)=6;
```

All I need to do (I think) is for function to stop when there is half of odd number and do a certain function;Here's my code:

```
if(n%2!=0){
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(i==((n/2)+1)){ // THIS PART
        length+=mas[(n/2)+1]-mas[n/2];
        i++;
        break;
    }
    length+=mas[i+1]-mas[i];
    i++;
}
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you expect to do when `n` is odd?

Comment: Yes, I got an idea as I said how to do it, but I don't know how to apply it

Comment: Please explain what is your problem clearly

Comment: I am not sure how to calculate the distance when the number (n) is odd. ( 5, 7, 9 etc), I displayed my code how I have tried to find a solution that calculates it correctly. However, I failed. So what I am asking is to help me correct the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_distance(int n, int a[n]){
    if(n < 2)
        return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int i=0;
    if(n & 1){//n is odd
        sum = a[1] - a[0];
        ++i;
    }
    for(;i<n; i+=2){
        sum += a[i+1] - a[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    int a[4] = { 0, 4, 10, 12};
    int b[5] = { 0, 2, 4, 10, 12};//they are sorted

    printf("%d\n", sum_distance(4, a));//6
    printf("%d\n", sum_distance(5, b));//6

    return 0;
 }
```